# Draw background height depending on a given value Android

Tags: android

I would like to have a background on my app that changes color depending on a given number. Let me elaborate some more. For example, I pass the number 40 out of 100, 2/5s of the screen should be x color, and the other 3/5s should be the other color. Here are two little diagrams:

```
40 / 100                   40/60
+---+                      +---+
|   | 3/5 not filled in    |   | 1/3 not filled in
|   |                      |...| 2/3 filled in
|   |                      |...|
|...| 2/5 filled in        +---+
|...|
+---+
```

So I was thinking I could go about making a dynamic background (giving a certain number) by drawing in the shapes. The problem is, I am not exactly sure how I would go about doing this. Where do I place the code to draw the shapes, and how exactly would I insert them into my XML file in the correct place (I already have a static color background that is up in my XML)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you need to create an activity with two Linear Layouts. The width attribute will be set to *match_parent* and the height to *0dp*. You will then be able to set the height with a layout weight of X %.

As an example, those layouts split the screen 25% 75% :

```
<LinearLayout

    layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout

    layout_weight="3"/>
```

Give them an id to change values programmatically (weight and background color).

You can do it this way :

```
LinearLayout top = findViewById(R.id.top);

//Third Param stands for weight
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1.0f);

top.setLayoutParams(param);
    top.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Oh, ingenious! :D How would I change their heights though, and where exactly?

Comment: If you change the weight when the height is set to 0dp, it will change the height

Comment: I will not know the height though in the XML, that I would need to change from the actual code.

Comment: I know. But when you will change the weight in java, the height will automatically change. Weight allows you to set in %. Set them to 50/50 in the xml and edit them in java, in onCreate or View listeners depending on your needs

Comment: Oh, very interesting! :) Now, when I set these View Listeners where exactly do I place them? In the java file for that XML file? Also, what piece of code will I use to change the weight?

Comment: Listeners are set in onCreate, in the java file related to the xml one (see setContentView). I updated the answer to show you how to change background Color and layout weight